# Как правильно связать две таблицы?

Tags: sql, база-данных

У меня есть две таблицы связанные отношением один-к-одному.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я правильно понимаю, что при добавлении нового пользователя, я сначала должен добавить его в таблицу **Authenticztion`**, узнать под каким **LoginId** он добавился и лишь потом добавлять запись в таблицу **Clients**, где и укажу полученный **LoginId**?

Исправьте меня, пожалуйста, если я делаю что то не так или же можно сделать более разумно и правильнее.

Comment: *У меня есть две таблицы связанные отношением один-к-одному.* Хотелось бы увидеть полные CREATE TABLE для обеих таблиц. Потому как из скриншота создаётся впечатление, что тут 1:N.

Answer (score 0):

в части связывания все верно, если имеет смысл разделение на 2 таблицы. В части самой таблицы, обратите внимание, на следующее

- `lastname` и `surname` это синомнимы, обозначающие фамилию. и в целом это слово целиком, CamelCase тут ни к месту.
- Также стоит обратить внимание на использование типа char, обычно это константная длина, чаще используют `varchar` переменной длины.
- врядли есть какой-либо смысл хранить серию и номер паспорта в отдельных полях, то что первые 4 цифры у многих совпадают и обозначают серию не значит что их надо разделять при хранении, номер без серии смысла не имеет.
- обратите внимание на тип данных `smallint`. Если серию паспорта вы в него еще впихаете, то ни номер паспорта ни номер телефона туда явно не поместятся.
- Вообще номер телефона не стоит хранить числом. И в целом, подумайте, возможно потребуется хранить несколько номеров телефонов для каждого клиента, тогда потребуется связь один-ко-многим.

зы. добавление записей логин-клиент можете обернуть в транзакцию. также надо обеспечить уникальность значения поля login

Comment: за замечания спасибо. Я разделил на 2 таблицы, потому что запросы с проверкой логина-пароля будут происходить чаще, поэтому.